# How to change the background colour of mat-select and change edge of select box to rounded style?

Tags: css, angular

Can anyone help me with changing the colour of `mat-select` box and how to style the box to have rounded corners.
I tried by giving it the `background-colour` property but it is not affecting my element.

**html**

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline"> 
       <mat-select class="topunit">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let x of filteredData [value]="x">{{x.name}} - {{x.place}} 
          </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

**css**

```
.topunit{
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding: 0 0.75em 0 0.75em;
    width: 75%;
    align-items: baseline;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Severals controls of material angular use cdk to create a div cdk-overlay-container outside our app. So if we want to change the .css we need use style.css (**not** the .css of the component)

Futhermore, usually this controls has a property: "PanelClass" that allow us only change this control -not all- (*)

So you can write in styles.css, e.g.

```
.topunit.mat-select-panel
{
  background-color: red;

}
```

And in your .html

```
<mat-select panelClass="topunit">
  ...
</mat-select>
```

(*) see that if we only write in styles.css

```
.mat-select-panel
{
  background-color: red;

}
```

All ours pannels with class mat-select-panel becomes red.

Comment: It changes the panel inside mat-select. I need help to change colour of mat-select box itself not panel.

Comment: perhafs you need change `.topunit .mat-option` class. Check the DOM using F12

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ::ng-deep to force a style down to `child components`. This selector had an alias, in this case ::ng-deep

EXAMPLE:

```
 ::ng-deep .mat-select-panel{
     background: red !important;
 }
```

this way you will override mat-select-panel background color.

the best way to find the classes you need to change is using the browser element inspector